# restore database gives error UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

I'm following this less than precise tutorial [Data Mining The City](http://datamining.city/2015/09/16/loading-the-dmc-databases/)

1. I've create the database from the studio and it shows in my
   databases folder as "soufun_db".
2. I downloaded the soufun.zip file into the directory db that I
       created in the orientdb folder
3. Then I connect to the"soufun_db" database from the console

   ```
   "CONNECT remote:localhost/soufun_db admin admin"
   ```
4. Then I run my restore database command

   ```
   "RESTORE DATABASE /home/mustafa/Desktop/orientdb-community-2.1.0/db/soufun.zip
   ```
5. Output is:

   ```
   "Restoring database database /home/.../soufun.zip
    Error: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: restore"
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BACKUP` and `RESTORE` operations are supported only via plocal connection.

http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Console-Command-Restore.html